# Is it possible to use Java 11 depended library in Java 8 application - Maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3

I am trying to include Java 11 depended library in Java 8 app.

getting below

```
java: cannot access com.test.Manager
  bad class file: /C:/com/test/my-test/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/my-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/test/Manager.class
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Both library and app has maven as build tool.

Is anyway to resolve this?

Comment: If you have an lib/app which uses JDK 8 to run you can't use a lib/dep which has been built with JDK11...